# Smarty Error: media_player.php is not readable

Tags: php, smarty

I copied a website from rareculture.net to my local machine so that I can work with it.  The site uses CS Cart, which uses Smarty, and I am getting the following error:

```
( ! ) Warning: Smarty error:     http://localhost/cscart/skins/projection/customer/media_player.php is not readable in  C:\wamp\www\cscart\lib\templater\Smarty.class.php on line 1095
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  676392  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.1292  14141136    fn_dispatch( )  ..\index.php:28
3   0.1890  16676848    Templater->display( )   ..\fn.control.php:505
4   0.1891  16677472    Smarty->display( )  ..\class.templater.php:122
5   0.1891  16677616    Smarty->fetch( )    ..\Smarty.class.php:1108
6   0.1920  17133376    include( 'C:\wamp\www\cscart\var\compiled\customer\%%45^45E^45E480CD%%index.tpl.php' )  ..\Smarty.class.php:1258
7   0.2102  17289304    Templater->_smarty_include( )   ..\%%45^45E^45E480CD%%index.tpl.php:394
8   0.2115  17454696    include( 'C:\wamp\www\cscart\var\compiled\customer\%%72^72D^72DAF6E8%%main.tpl.php' )   ..\class.templater.php:88
9   0.2378  17828056    smarty_core_smarty_include_php( )   ..\%%72^72D^72DAF6E8%%main.tpl.php:141
10  0.2384  17852528    smarty_core_get_php_resource( ) ..\core.smarty_include_php.php:25
11  0.2397  17874168    Smarty->trigger_error( )    ..\core.get_php_resource.php:66
12  0.2397  17874432    trigger_error ( )   ..\Smarty.class.php:1095
```

At first, the path was not right to media_player.php for my local server, and it was giving me 3 errors.  After changing the path to main.tpl here:

```
<div id="homepage-meida">
{include_php file='http://localhost/cscart/skins/projection/customer/media_player.php}
</div><!-- #homepage-media -->
```

I got just the one error.  I tried changing the permissions in Windows 7, giving Everyone full access to both the file and the containing folder, and it didn't change anything.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I'm using WAMP on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Did you try a path to the file instead of the URL? I was not aware that you could even use URLs with `{include}`? It might be looking for a directory called `http://localhost...` I thought you had to use a path relative to Smarty `$template_dir` or `$trusted_dir` or something...

Comment: I tried file='///c:/wamp/www/cscart/skins/projection/customer', file='//localhost/c:/wamp/www/cscart/skins/projection/customer', file='/cscart/skins/projection/customer', along with any other combination I could think of.  Other paths gave me additional errors, which got me to thinking I got the path right but the permissions wrong?

Comment: Try adding the php into a new .tpl file then call the template {include file="$tpl_name.tpl"}

or try with double quotes

{include_php file="/path/to/somefile.php"}